# countif within R repeated across each row

Tags: r, sum, countif

I'm having trouble trying to replicate some of the countif function I'm familiar with in excel.  I've got a data frame, and it has a large number of rows.  I'm trying to take 2 variables (x & z) and do a countif of how many other variables within my dataframe match that.  I figured out doing:

```
sum('mydataframe'$x==`mydataframe`$x[1]&`mydataframe'$z==`mydataframe`$z[1])
```

This gives me the correct countif for x&z within the whole data set for the first row [1]. The problem is I've got to use that [1]. I've tried using the (with,...) command, but then I can no longer access the whole column.

I'd like to be able to do the count of x & z combination for each row within the data frame then have that output as a new vector that I can just add as another column.  And I'd like this to go on for every row through to the end.

Hopefully this is pretty simple. I figure some combination of (with,..) or apply or something will do it, but I'm just too new.

I am interested in a count total in every instance, not a running sequential count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are asking for a way to create a new column that contains the number of rows in the entire data frame with `x` and `z` value equal to the values of those variables for that row.

With a bit of sample data:

```
(dat <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 2), z=c(3, 3, 3)))
#   x z
# 1 1 3
# 2 1 3
# 3 2 3
```

One simple approach would be grouping with `dplyr`'s `group_by` function and then creating a new column with the number of elements in that group:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(x, z) %>% mutate(n=n())
#       x     z     n
#   (dbl) (dbl) (int)
# 1     1     3     2
# 2     1     3     2
# 3     2     3     1
```

A base R solution would probably involve `ave`:

```
dat$n <- ave(rep(NA, nrow(dat)), dat$x, dat$z, FUN=length)
dat
#   x z n
# 1 1 3 2
# 2 1 3 2
# 3 2 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table` would  be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`) , group by 'x', 'z' and
assign 'n' as the number of elements in each group (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, n:= .N, by = .(x,z)]
dat
#   x z n
#1: 1 3 2
#2: 1 3 2
#3: 2 3 1
```